# Facebook box with likes - how to set up count of avatars in the box?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

In the generated Facebook box is displayed 10 people's avatars, but I would like to display 12.
Is there any way to do it?
I don't see it in the available attributes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I cannot access FB or FB devs from work but as I recall, this can be done by increasing the height/width attributes.

Also, please include code snippets in questions on StackOverflow. Good luck.